# Category nicename inside loop in wordpress

Tags: categories, loop

How can I echo the current post's category nicename inside main loop.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 echo <div class="btn category-nicename"> 

 <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I want to echo the category nicename inside div tag as a class and then want to target the css

Any suggestions?

Comment: In which template do you want to use this

Comment: In category template

Comment: OK will post revised code now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) inside the loop to get the category/ies a post is assigned to. To get a list of available member variables available, see [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).

I would suggest to target the first category only, which will also be the parent category if the post is assigned to only one parent and some of the parent's child categories. Here is an example to get the first category assigned to a post's nicename

```
$category = get_the_category(); 
$post_cat = $category[0]->category_nicename;
```

You can now use `$post_cat` as your class. Just remember to add this code before this line

```
echo <div class="btn category-nicename">
```

Just a word of advice here, do not abuse `echo`. Use php tags where necessary to avoid using the unnecessary use of `echo`. BTW, your syntax is wrong

```
echo <div class="btn category-nicename">
```

should be

```
echo '<div class="btn category-nicename">';
```

if you are going to use `echo`

**EDIT**

From your comment above ^^, you need to get the current category's nice name. You can get the current category with `get_query_var( 'cat')` and from that you can get the nice name

```
$category = get_query_var( 'cat' );
$post_cat = $category->category_nicename;
```

As above, just use `$post_cat` in your class. I hope this answers your question